# DDL command commits transaction even if it fails

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I ran the below query.

```
insert into emp(id,name) values(1,'ONKAR');
```

then I wrote

```
Create table emp(id number(10));
```

it failed because emp table already exist.

then I ran

```
rollback;
```

then

```
select * from emp;
```

it is returning 1 row.

I know any DDL command after DML will commit the data. But why it is committing even when DDL command failed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because Oracle issues a commit both before and after DDL, as per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4010.htm#SQLRF01110):

> Oracle Database issues an implicit COMMIT under the following circumstances:
>
> - Before any syntactically valid data definition language (DDL) statement, even if the statement results in an error
> - After any data definition language (DDL) statement that completes without an error